# Elementwise minimum of two images in C++ using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I have 2 images of the Mat datatype of OpenCV. I wanted to get the element wise minimum(minimum value for a given index among both images) of both the images in another Mat. Is there a fast way of doing that other than comparing values at both indexes and iterating through the whole image? I am unsure on how to do this in C++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're looking for this: [`MatExpr min(const Mat& a, const Mat& b)`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#MatExpr%20min(const%20Mat&%20a,%20const%20Mat&%20b)):

> Calculates per-element minimum of two arrays or an array and a scalar.